# Concatenation of date (in date datatype) and time (in time datatype) in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Does concatenation in php make a difference. Lets say I have a time_in column (time datatype) and date_in column    (date datatype) in my database.

Example:

```
id | time_in | time_out |   date_in   |   date_out  | 
 1 | 9:30pm  | 7:30am   | 2013-12-01  |  2013-13-01 |
```

And in the table in which I will display it it shows like this;

```
id | Date & Time Login | Date & Time Logout |
 1 | 2013-12-01 9:30pm | 2013-13-01 7:30am  |
```

So far I do this in my script;

> echo $row ['date_in' . 'time_in'];

In the table it shows 2013-12-01Array and says that array to string conversion?

How do i do this in small and clean script?
Do I need another query for this?

Do I need to use SELECT CONCAT?

Any suggestions.

Comment: difference yes it depends up on the time zone of mysql and apache server ...dont depend upon timezone use utc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?PHP
$conn=mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(ur_dbname, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
$query="SELECT * FROM ur_table_name";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());    
echo "<table style='text-align:center'; cellpadding='3' cellspacing='5'><th><tr><td>ID</td><td colspan='2'>Time_i</td><td colspan='2'>Date_i</td></tr></th>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result) )
    {
       $dis="<tr><td>".$row['id']." </td><td>|</td><td> ".$row['time_i']." </td><td>|</td><td> ".$row['date_i']."</td><td>|</td></tr>";
       echo $dis;
    }
echo "</table>";
?>
```

i think this may work for you -- adn -- output will be

```
ID        Time_i           Date_i
1   |    11:08:40   |    2013-03-06 |
2   |    11:11:46   |    2013-03-06 |
3   |    00:00:00   |    2013-03-06 |
4   |    00:00:00   |    2013-03-06 |
5   |    11:16:40   |    2013-03-06 |
6   |    11:16:54   |    2013-03-06 |
```

you can try this also

```
echo $row['id']." | ".$row['time']." | ".$row['date'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ','date_in','time_in') AS datetime_in, CONCAT_WS(' ','date_out','time_out') AS datetime_out FROM table;
```

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. Concat two variable as per your need.

```
For Date & Time Login : $login  = $row['date_in']." ".$row['time_in'];
For Date & Time Logout : $logout = $row['date_out']." ".$row['time_out'];
```

Comment: i prefer this syntax :)

$login = "$row[date_in] $row[time_in]";